# trigonometric relation solution

Tags: trigonometry

Given the relation

$$ \tan x = \tan y \;\cos i,
$$

what is the simplest expression (not involving inverse trigonometric functions) for

$$ \sin2(x-z).
$$

in terms of $y$, $i$ and $z$ only?

So far, I obtained rather lengthy expressions from the doubling and difference formulas for the sine function in conjunction with
\begin{align}
\cos x = \frac{\cos y}{\sqrt{\cos^2\!y + \sin^2\!y\cos^2\!i}}
,\\
\sin x = \frac{\sin y\;\cos i}{\sqrt{\cos^2\!y + \sin^2\!y\cos^2\!i}},
\end{align}
but I'm hoping for something better. In particular, I would like a formula that trivially and obviously obtains $\sin2(y-z)$ in case of $\cos i=1$ and $\sin2(-y-z)$ for $\cos i=-1$

Answer (score 0):

Apply $\sin(A-B)$ in $$\sin(2x-2z)$$

Now use https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution to find $$\sin2x,\cos2x$$ in terms of $y,i$

Comment: That is essentially what I've got already. (only that I used cos and sin instead of tan).

Comment: @Walter, then simplify

Comment: Exactly. But I couldn't. At least not in such a way that the result meets my requirement (see edited post).